# Is it impolite/incorrect to start an email with "Namaste [name]"?

Tags: word-choice, email

When writing an email, should I start with just "Hello [name]" or can I use other greetings, such as, "Ni Hao [name]" or "Namaste [name]"?

I feel like it might be okay, but wonder if there is a cultural norm that I would be violating and I want to be respectful.

If this is the wrong SE, please let me know.

Comment: As *Ni Hao* and *Namaste* are not English terms, it seems inappropriate to ask about their use here.

Comment: Can you suggest an alternate location?  It does relate to email from an english speaker.

Comment: I've known a couple of  people who, at one time, at least, had affected the use of "Namaste" when writing informal communications.  It depends on how informal you're being and how you relate to the person being addressed.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because *Ni Hao* and *Namaste* are not English terms.

Comment: I agree with @HotLicks. It will entirely depend on your working relationship with the other party and what language they speak and understand. I don't think this question is on-topic here as it is not a discussion forum for social norm. If you are not sure, it is best not to use them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I am from India, I think I can answer this question since Namaste is a respectful form of greeting here in India. Though in our formal mails we do not use Namaste Mr X, we use Hi or Dear as the salutation but in case someone not from India uses this salutation while addressing an Indian it just shows a respectful gesture and there is nothing violating or offending in it.

Answer (score 2):

The answer to questions like this is: **it depends entirely on your context.**

Some people will find the greeting annoying. Some will find it endearing. Some won't care either way. Your coworker that sits next to you all day might be fine with it, but your CEO might not. It depends entirely on who you're sending it to, what setting you're in, etc.

This has very little to do with grammar or other language rules, and more to do with workplace and social etiquette.

You might try the [workplace](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/) or [academia](https://academia.stackexchange.com/) Stack Exchanges, depending on where you're writing these emails.